# How to avoid mutable and immutable borrows simultaneously

Tags: rust

How to get rid of the error related to simultaneous mutable and immutable borrowing in my below code

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct A {
    val: i32,
    hash_map: HashMap<i32, i32>,
}

fn foo(a_obj: &mut A) {
    a_obj.val = 3;
    let k = 1;
    let hm = a_obj.hash_map.get_mut(&k);
    if let Some(val_part) = hm {
        if a_obj.hash_map.len() > 1 {
            *val_part = 0;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a_obj = A {
        val: 0,
        hash_map: Default::default(),
    };
    
    foo(&mut a_obj);
}
```

I don't like the idea of getting size of `HashMap<i32, i32>` before getting mutable borrow. Is there a better way to handle this kind of problem.

Comment: _"I don't like the idea of getting size of `HashMap<i32, i32>` before getting mutable borrow."_ --  why not? That's the answer to your question!

Comment: You may want to use the [`entry()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) function here.

Comment: If you just don't like the idea of using a variable to hold the `len()`, go ahead and do it even though you dislike it. It is the proper solution. If you have a better reason to avoid it, well, you need to tell us what it is.

Answer (score 4):

The issue you're facing is related to Rust's borrowing rules. The Rust compiler ensures memory safety without a garbage collector by analyzing the various aspects of pointers, such as whether they are used for reading or writing, and whether it is safe to do so concurrently.

In your code, you're trying to get a mutable reference to a value in the `HashMap` while holding an immutable reference to the `HashMap` itself. This violates Rust's borrowing rules, which state that you can't have a mutable reference while you have an immutable one.

```rust
let hm = a_obj.hash_map.get_mut(&k); // Mutable reference to a value in the HashMap.
if a_obj.hash_map.len() > 1 { // Immutable reference to the HashMap.
    *val_part = 0;
}
```

This rule is in place to prevent data races at compile time.

To fix this, you need to separate the check for the length of the `HashMap` from the mutation of the value.

```rust
fn foo(a_obj: &mut A) {
    a_obj.val = 3;
    let k = 1;
    if a_obj.hash_map.len() > 1 {
        if let Some(val_part) = a_obj.hash_map.get_mut(&k) {
            *val_part = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

We first check if the length of the `HashMap` is greater than 1. If it is, we then get a mutable reference to the value and update it. This way, we're never holding a mutable and an immutable reference at the same time, which is why this code doesn't violate Rust's borrowing rules.

This approach doesn't require getting the size of the `HashMap` before getting the mutable reference, it only requires checking the condition before getting the mutable reference

Comment: Well you're still "getting the size before getting the mutable reference", but it doesn't matter for the problem.

Comment: You could get a race condition if you check for length before doing some kind of locking, like it is done with ˋget_mutˋ.

Comment: @Markus then explain to me how you can run code that holds an **exclusive reference** concurrently without UB.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't like the idea of getting size of `HashMap<i32, i32>` before getting mutable borrow. Is there a better way to handle this kind of problem.

`HashMap::len()` borrows `self`. That means you absolutely cannot call it at the same time as having a mutable borrow of the hashmap.

I guess that your objection here is that the mutable borrow in your code cannot actually change the size, so it shouldn't matter. That's true! But Rust's type system is not able to express this idea. So you just need to access the length before you mutably access the map.

Comment: No, there is Cell and RefCell

Comment: @Markus It would be bad advice to tell someone to introduce interior mutability _solely_ to avoid introducing a local variable.

Comment: You don't put the HashMap in the Cell, you put the values, you want to modify in the cell. See my answer.

Answer (score -7):

One possibility, use

> std::cell::Cell

or *RefCell*.

Like in...

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aec24f44eef1ae31a6e25d52b556a5ca

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct A {
    val: i32,
    hash_map: HashMap<i32, Cell<i32>>,
}

fn foo(a_obj: &mut A) {
    a_obj.val = 3;
    let k = 1;
    let hm_entry = a_obj.hash_map.get(&k);
    if let Some(val_part) = hm_entry {
        if a_obj.hash_map.len() > 1 {
            val_part.set(0);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a_obj = A {
        val: 0,
        hash_map: Default::default(),
    };

    foo(&mut a_obj);
}
```

Comment: While this is technically true, it's solving a problem that doesn't really exist, while introducing unnecessary complexity and runtime overhead.

Comment: Then post your answer, that we understand where there isn't a problem. The problem is described in OP's question.

Comment: Btw, there shouldn't be runtime overhead. Cell is for borrow checker and checked during compile time. Memory layout is the same.

Comment: As Peter earlier stated this is not a good solution. This changes the type of `hash_map`, which might not be possible and does not address the real OP's question, which was already answered. Moreover this can be harmful to new users, because they could try "solve" their borrow-checker errors by not solving them at all, and instead to such workarounds as proposed.

Comment: And now we can only read from the map if the original values implement `Copy` quite the unnecessary restriction for a problem that doesn't really exist. The function gets an exclusive reference, so there are no concurrency considerations to be taken into account.

Comment: Also if the compiler is smart it's very well allowed to reorder that so that the expensive calculation of the hash in `get` is only performed *after* the check against the length.